# How to add Cancel/Ok button within Minicart and remove popup

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, mini-cart, magento2.3.0

I want to **remove** the delete button that is in **below screenshot**

[image]

And add to button **Cancel/Ok** within **minicart**, not in popup like magneto by default functionality.
just want to add button on mincart **not on popup, remove popup**.

[image]

> kindly help me out!

[image]

[image]

just one thing i want add a massage of **Are you sure you want to Remove**
after clicking the

> Remove item

button

Comment: If you remove delete button then which action you want to trigger for `Cancel` and `Ok` button?

Comment: i just want to remove the popup, and add that action on the minicart, like we have a button on minicart name "Remove" on clicking the remove button it show two option for "cancel" and "Ok" within minicart not on popup, as simple as that, kindly help me out im very thankfull of you:)

Comment: dont remove action button just want to remove the popup and trigger the same remove action of cancel and ok within the mincart

Comment: Why do you need to add Cancel and OK button over there? you just need to bypass confirmation popup right? I think you don't need to put that buttons in minicart

Comment: i just need to put on popup button in minicart not needed the popup, after click on the remove button on minicart, there appears two button of OK and Confirm on mincart for the action trigger for delete the product like as in json popup doing @AasimGoriya

Comment: @AasimGoriya i dont need popup just doing popup functionality on minicart as simple kindly help me if you can?

Comment: @MuneshJalwani please check my answer.

Comment: you can follow this link :
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-show-additional-data-on-mini-cart-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all please override sidebar.js file in your custom theme.

So In theme, add a js file `sidebar.js` to `app\design\frontend\[NAMESPACE]\[THEME]\Magento_Checkout\web\js\sidebar.js` if not exist then copy form `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js`

Now go to `button.remove` function in `sidebar.js` on line number `89 approx`, and replace the whole function with the following code.

```
/**
 * @param {jQuery.Event} event
 */
events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    /* Start code ok/cancel code */
    var ok = document.createElement("button");
    ok.innerHTML = "ok";

    var confirmtext = document.createElement("div");
    confirmtext.innerHTML = $.mage.__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?')

    var cancel = document.createElement("button");
    cancel.innerHTML = "cancel";

    confirmtext.classList.add("rmprod");
    ok.classList.add("rmprod");
    cancel.classList.add("rmprod");

    var prnt = $(event.target).parents('.product-item-details');

    if(!prnt.has('.rmprod').length){
        prnt.append(confirmtext);
        prnt.append(ok);
        prnt.append(cancel);
    }

    ok.addEventListener ("click", function() {
      self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
    });

    cancel.addEventListener ("click", function() {
      $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog('close');
      prnt.children('.rmprod').remove();
    });

    // confirm({
    //     content: self.options.confirmMessage,
    //     actions: {
    //         /** @inheritdoc */
    //         confirm: function () {
    //             self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
    //         },

    //         /** @inheritdoc */
    //         always: function (e) {
    //             e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //         }
    //     }
    // });
};
```

You can manage remove button from following file in your custom theme.

```
/app/design/frontend/[NAMESPACE]/[THEME]/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

find the following in your `default.html` file.
You can change the text following code and remove the button style using CSS.

```
<div class="secondary">
   <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}" class="action delete">
       <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove Item'"></span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give me the screenshot of your end? did you got the same thing that i want?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with my local code and its working fine, I have removed code from my end so I don't have a screenshot for now, but you can try this code and it will definitely work, please try first and then let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Yes, it works, checked

Comment: @AasimGoriya just one thing i want, please check my updated question!

Comment: @AasimGoriya just want to add the message after clicking the remove item button, i Want Remove item button instead of cross symbol so please update your code and add the remove button and message also on clicking the Remove button "Are you sure you want to Remove" so please do the last thing and update

Comment: @MuneshJalwani you can just add a message before append ok button like this `$(event.target).parents('.product-item-details').append('<label>are you sure you want to remove?</label>');` please see my updated ans for more information.

Comment: I have added a label with translation. Hope you don't mind @AasimGoriya

Comment: @AasimGoriya can you please add the label for "Remove item" button.like in my screenshot above. For know its shows the cross symbol, just last thing can you add this plz?

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang ah that's fine, I don't mind that, and thanks for correcting me (y)

Comment: @MuneshJalwani do you need a close button with the remove item label? If so then do you need to set any action on that?

Comment: i just need a button in replace of cross symbol! like if we press button it show our option of cancel and ok, that button name is "Remove Item" just last thing

Comment: @MuneshJalwani Check my updated answer

Comment: @AasimGoriya i got the button, but one issue is occuring that if we press the remove button once it shows the option, if we press the twice it open another option below the first occur option! means if we press many time this button it will open multiple option one to another. its functionality error can you plz resolve this, if we click onces it open the option, if we click second time it hide the option, rather then reopen the new option, can you please resolve this through functionality!

Comment: @AasimGoriya thank you man:)